# what is the END parameter in python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a simple python3 code down below:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
e = Entry(root,width=30)
e.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)
e.delete(0,END)
root.mainloop()
```

My question is, what is `END` argument at the 5th line. I mean it is not a string then what is it?? also this is not a variable. If I pass a variable as a parameter to a function, it needs to be predefined. Then where the `END` parameter comes from ???

Answer (score 3):

It is the string "end". "end" is a special value for the  `Entry` widget method `delete`. It means "the end of the text"

It was imported from the tkinter module when you did `from tkinter import *`.

This is a good illustration of why wildcard imports aren't the preferred way to import modules - it hides the origin of variables, functions, and classes, and makes the code arguably just a little harder to understand. If the code had done `import tkinter as tk` and subsequently used `tk.END` then it would have been obvious where it came from.

Comment: You can verify this with `file>open module` function of the IDLE. Choose the`tkinter` module: you’ll normally see the `END` variable, defined to `"end"`. @Abdul_Kuddus

Answer (score 0):

It's just a string 'end', but it has a special meaning, in the tkinter code (to allow you to delete all the text in your example).  But that doesn't mean that you have to pass a string there.  I.e. if you don't pass in END, then you might pass in an int - a numerical index for the end of the range you want to delete. e.g..

```
e.delete(0,5)
```

.. which would delete the first four characters.

From the docs ([https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#:~:text=END%20(or%20%E2%80%9Cend%E2%80%9D),change%20this%20from%20the%20program.](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#:%7E:text=END%20(or%20%E2%80%9Cend%E2%80%9D),change%20this%20from%20the%20program.)),

*"END (or “end”) corresponds to the position just after the last character in the entry widget. The range (0, END) corresponds to all characters in the widget."*